# How can I loop or RegEx through a text stream in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bigdata

I need to look for patterns in huge text files (around 100 billion characters) that I can only viably access through a URL. Before the files got so big, I was just running a for loop through a `str` input with this function:

```
def check_text_for_pattern(source_text, substring_size):
    substrings_counter = 0
    unique_substrings = [""]
    is_unique = True
    print("Looking for desired patterns within source text")
    for x in range(len(source_text)):
        substring_candidate = source_text[x - 1: substring_size + x - 1]
        ***pattern rules***
            for y in unique_substrings:
                if y == substring_candidate:
                    is_unique = False
            if is_unique:
                print("New unique substring found: " + substring_candidate)
                unique_substrings[substrings_counter] = substring_candidate
                substrings_counter += 1
            is_unique = True
    return unique_substrings
```

It is working well, but I can't seem to figure out the right way to loop through data that is not completely loaded from the very start, partially because a data stream has no `len` property. How can I keep moving through character subsets without missing any in a scenario like that? Also, since there are multiple files to run through now, how do I signal my code that end of file has been reached so it can move on to the next URL?

Comment: What is the size of the alphabet used in the strings? ASCII letters, DNA letters, ...? What are typical values for `substring_size`?

Comment: It's all numerical digits ranging from 0 to 9 with UTF-8 encoding and the values for ```substring_size``` usually range from 10 to 20 depending on the pattern